I was trying to apply gradient descent manually, but facing a problem
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
#Creating Random X and Y Value
np.random.seed(405)
X = 6*np.random.rand(100,1)-3
Y = 0.8*(X**2) + 0.9*X + 2 + np.random.randn(100,1)
Y = Y.reshape(-1,1)
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.2,random_state=2)
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2,include_bias=False)
X_train_trans = poly.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_trans = poly.transform(X_test)
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train_trans,y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test_trans)
print(model.intercept_)
print(model.coef_)
n = len(X_train_trans)
β0 = 0
β1 = 1
β2 = 2
learning_rate = 0.0001  # Adjusted learning rate
num_iterations = 50000  # Increased iterations
n = len(X_train_trans)
for iteration in range(num_iterations):
   # Compute predictions
   y_prediction = β0 + β1 * X_train_trans[:, 0] + β2 * X_train_trans[:, 1]

   # Compute the loss (Mean Squared Error)
   loss = (1/(2*n)) * np.sum((y_train - y_prediction)**2)

   # Compute gradients
   d_β0 = -(1 / n) * np.sum(y_train - y_prediction)
   d_β1 = -(1 / n) * np.sum((y_train - y_prediction) * X_train_trans[:, 0])
   d_β2 = -(1 / n) * np.sum((y_train - y_prediction) * X_train_trans[:, 1])

   # Update parameters
   β0 -= learning_rate * d_β0
   β1 -= learning_rate * d_β1
   β2 -= learning_rate * d_β2

   # Print loss and parameters periodically
   if iteration % 1000 == 0:
      print(f"Iteration {iteration}: Loss = {loss}")

print(f"Final parameters (Gradient Descent): β0 = {β0}, β1 = {β1}, β2 = {β2}")

The problem is that each and every time I get different values of coefficients from the linear regression model and my manually applied model, I am unable to understand why. I have also tried changing the learning rate and number of iterations, but i am unable to get the same value for both. Can you help me out?
I had a question regarding polynomial regression gradient descent. I want its answer if possible.

The indentation of your code is incorrect What part of the code was inside the for loop? (likely all but the last line, but please update your question)

Running your code (with the code block underneath for indented except for the last line) prints the same result reliably. It's possible you get a different result on a different machine, due to Python or library version differences, but on the same machine you should be seeing the same results repeatedly. (I happen to be running Python 3.12.0, scikit-learn 1.4.1.post1, numpy 1.26.4 - but I doubt the specific versions matter than much)

Sir, the fact is that i am literally getting a lot differnce between the coefficient values of the scikit learn applied model and my manually applied gradient descent model. I am unable to understand why. By the way my all modules are of the latet version and I am also using Python 3.12.0 . The indentation is updated now. Please let me know if you can remove my confusion.

Maybe you can provide a few more details about how you're running this, on what platform, in what way, and how do you get the results? Perhaps share a few as well?

I am running it in jupyter note book, which i have downlaoded from vs code as an extention.

Given that you're running in a Jupyter Notebook, are you rerunning all the code every time, including the np.random.seed(405)?

yes, what is the ouput difference for you?? Do you not notice some significant difference between two outputs?

When I create a Jupyter Notebook, run it, put your code in a cell, run the cell - every time I run the cell, I get identical output. So, either you're running more than just a basic Notebook, or you're splitting up the code, or there is some other difference. Also, from the code alone, given that you're providing a seed, it doesn't make sense for you not to get the same output every time. Have you tested running the code repeatedly as you posted?

print(model.intercept_): [1.81418418]                                                                                         print(model.coef_): [[0.79254092 0.82327779]]                                                                         print(f"Final parameters (Gradient Descent): β0 = {β0}, β1 = {β1}, β2 = {β2}"):                        Final parameters (Gradient Descent): β0 = 4.693639401494847, β1 = -5.1117926467067145e-15, β2 = 2.745293677655435e-14                                                   so it is my ouput,clearly you can check out the ouput differemce

Sir can you help me out??

Again, it looks like you're running the last bit of code separate from the earlier ones. What you put in your comment suggests you're running commands separate from each other. If you run the entire section of code all at once, repeatedly, you will see the same results. You'll need to carefully read my comments and do as instructed - otherwise I (nor anyone else really) can't help

Sir i am running the whole code at a time. I also tried not to separate the code into few bolcks in jupyter notebook. But still after keeping it in one block, I am getting the same result again and again. I also treid some external interpretor, but still getting same result.

If you set up a simple Python environment for Python 3.12, install jupyter and scikit-learn, start jupyter lab and then paste the code in your question (minus unneeded pandas and matplotlib imports) in a cell, you can run it repeatedly and it will give the same result every time. Whatever you're doing must be different somehow - without providing more information about what you're doing exactly, everyone can repeat this procedure and get the same outcome. Your issue cannot be reproduced as it stands.

No no, I think you misunderstood the question, I was not saying that I am getting different results for a particular random seed, I was saying that the way in which i applied my gradient descent algorithm manually is not giving same result as of the result of polynomial regression applied from the scikit-learn module, there is a huge difference between the two results, which I commented above. So there is my doubt, why both results are differing from each other so much. Is there any problem in my implementation of the gradient descent algorithm?? I hope you understood what I am asking.

I see, have you tried varying the learning rate? It seems fairly low. Also, your gradient descent depends on initial values, where sklearn's result is independent of initial values. You could try varying those and see if you get better results - to come up with a better default. I haven't checked your computation in any detail, so obviously there could be small mistakes there. The best way to test that is by testing it on test data that has an unambiguous known outcome, and then progressively testing more realistic test sets.

hey,https://www.kaggle.com/code/jitroy0506/gradient-descent-implementation-manually here i found my error finally, if you are liitle bit interested then check it out

If you found a solution to your issue, consider writing a brief answer. Do include relevant information that would help someone else solve it instead of just the link, if you can. This will cause your question to no longer show up as unanswered, which makes it more useful to others, and saves people looking for questions to answer time.
